# Do I own GPLv3 code that I wrote?

Tags: licensing, commercial, gpl-3

This is a hypothetical question, that has not happened, so please no advice. If I publish some code on GitHub with the GPLv3 license, then want to use that code in proprietary software that I will also own. Do I have the rights to use it for monetary purposes?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [So the GPL doesn't restrict the creator of the software in any way?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/2077/50)