# Can I sell my project using GNU GPL v3?

Tags: licensing, gpl-3, commercial, gnu

At first, I always developed commercial projects only, so I bad know GNU licenses. Now, I want to make my library available for other developers. And maybe to find co-developers. So, I chosen GNU GPL v3... **BUT**
I didn't get how does this license apply to me?

1. Can I use own GNU GPL v3 library in my commercial projects?
2. Can I use own GNU GPL v3 library in my commercial projects if some
   developer modified its sources too?

Comment: By "commercial products" do you mean "closed source commercial products"?

Comment: Yeah, a software that will shared like proprietary software and include this GNU GPL v3 library (as dynamic or static linked).

Comment: If the first and second items of my question have differences I need to know it too.

Comment: Looks like [So the GPL doesn't restrict the creator of the software in any way?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/so-the-gpl-doesnt-restrict-the-creator-of-the-software-in-any-way/2078#2078) probably answers both of your questions (items #1 and #4 there).

Comment: There has this string **If a project includes copyrighted work from multiple contributors, then licensing the project requires consent from all copyright holders.**.

Comment: I.e. if some one made a commit to my repository then will I need to get his consent to use this code unlimited?

Comment: Sorry, just I bad understand how to other members (not author) become contributors. When do they make approved commit in the repository? Or should I add them to `contributors.txt` file? Can you explain just a bit, please?

Comment: At iText, we require code contributors to sign a Contributor License Agreement. If they don't sign such an agreement, we don't accept the code. That is explained in the question about the GPL and the creator of the software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Can I use own GNU GPL v3 library in my commercial projects?

Yes, as long as you own the rights to your own code, you could license it to other under the GPL for free or commercially for a fee. For instance this is the business model of MySQL.

2. Can I use own GNU GPL v3 library in my commercial projects if some developer modified its sources too?

Yes, as you as you own the rights to this code which may require a [contributor license agreement](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contributor-agreements) such that external contributions rights are licensed to you in a way that would allow you to relicense under a commercial license.