# Do I need to share source code with GPL/AGPL if I am the owner?

Tags: gpl, license

if I build something under GPL/AGPL license, am I obligated to share that code if I have users using this service event when I am the owner of the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [So the GPL doesn't restrict the creator of the software in any way?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/2077/50)